# Getting NTLM security token from IE

Tags: internet-explorer, ntlm, http-authentication, moniker

I have an ActiveX that deploys some application on the client machine and starts it.
When using NTLM on the IIS, the authentication with the web server done by IE and there is no problem to download files (I'm using URL Monikers API) but when an ActiveX starts the application (application also needs an access to the server) there is a need to do the authentication again.

I'm asking if there is a way to avoid second time authentication.

Thanks,
Zaky

Comment: /me shudders at the thought that people are still using ActiveX controls in the brower. (I know it's probably a legacy app that you have to maintain, but for myself I hope I never see another one again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both WinINET and URLMon maintain per-process caches of credential information; this information is not available to other processes. In order to provide the credentials to the other process, you would have to transfer them from the current IE process to the other process. Unfortunately, there are no supported APIs for that task.

Typically, however, environments that use NTLM/Negotiate tend to use the user's default credentials, which the URLMon APIs should be able to use if the appropriate flags are set.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer ! One more question, do you know how to get an access to that per-process cache? Can I have an access to the packet headers for example and path the data to the other process using various win32 mechanisms?

Comment: Sorry, as I said, there are no supported APIs for that task. There are no APIs that access the process' credential cache.